# Determine the middle space of a string and split into 2 strings ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, string, split

I have a string that I am splitting into 2 Strings like this:

```
string a="Hello World here i am ";
if(a.Length > 10)
{
    string[] result = a.Split(' '); // Divides string into 2 where there is a Space this is type of array 
    string C = result[0]; // This takes the 1st value of that array 
    string D = result[1];);//This takes the  value of that array
    Console.WriteLine(C);
    Console.WriteLine(D);
}
```

This is a example Console Lines to test real, work I am going to need 2 string to put comments in 2 lines in a comment box.

So this string `a` could be anything, the problem is I have only 2 lines. I want to split it from the space that is in the middle of this string for example, a code that counts the number of characters such as there in example `a.Length > 10` and then find the space that is in the middle of this string in this example it is `Hello World here I am` here it should see `Hello world` in one string and here I am into another string any help? I tried looking at alots of examples such as these:

```
string s = "there is a cat";
//
// Split string on spaces.
// ... This will separate all the words.
//
string[] words = s.Split(' ');
foreach (string word in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

This splits these into couple of lines as well as don't really return 2 strings I want 2 string only. Thanks in Advance

Comment: `s.Length/2` gives you index of middle character. Now use SubString method to get string before and after of middle character

Comment: You need to specify exactly which space you want the string to be split on an the rules to determine that.  So do you want "there" and "is a cat" or "there is" and "a cat" or maybe "there is a" and "cat"?

Comment: @juharr As I said in the question it is a comment box it could be anything user can type anything I don't know which word it was a example to set and just want to split into 2 strings from the middle

Comment: s.Length/2 will give  it a try but wont it break a word \

Comment: @HaseebAhmad So the middle space? Would that be the space that results in two string that are as close to the same length as possible or the n/2 space where n is the number of spaces?  So would "a a a a a reallylongword" split into "a a a" and "a a reallylongword" or "a a a a a" and "reallylongword"?

Comment: The middle space or any space that's close to the middle to avoid a broken work I need it to break on a space that's close to the middle of the string

Comment: @HaseebAhmad Sounds like you want Steve's 2nd solution then.

Comment: Yes it worked I am using that Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do that with a some IEnumerable extensions like Take and Skip

```
string a = "This is a long phrase to test the splitting around the middle space";
string[] parts = a.Split(' ');
string first = string.Join(" ", parts.Take(parts.Length / 2));
string second = string.Join(" ", parts.Skip(parts.Length / 2));
Console.WriteLine(first);
Console.WriteLine(second);
```

However, this is not really the best approach because this method doesn't count the words length and thus you could end with a line a lot shorter than the other.

If you need to have two strings about the same length then you could use a loop like this

```
string a = "This is a long text to test the splitting around the middle length of the phrase";
string[] parts = a.Split(' ');

int counter = 0;
string first = "";
int middle = a.Length / 2;
while (first.Length < middle)
{
    first += parts[counter] + " ";
    counter++;
}
string second = string.Join(" ", parts.Skip(counter));
Console.WriteLine(first);
Console.WriteLine(second);
```